# select("Acura", :from=>'js-emu-make-id', visible: false) is not reflected when running save_and_open_page. It still appears to be blank. Why?

Tags: javascript, ruby, capybara

I am practicing/testing capybara and ran into a problem with selecting items from a dropdown menu.

The way the website works is that you can only go to the next dropdown if you filled in the one before and I am able to fill in the last dropdown but when I open the page, the previous two boxes remain empty.

---

internet = Capybara.current_session

url = "https://repairpal.com/estimator"

internet.visit url

internet.select("Acura", :from=>'js-emu-make-id', visible: false)

internet.select("1993", :from=>'js-emu-year-id', visible: false)

internet.select('Integra', :from=>'js-emu-base-vehicle-id', visible: false)

internet.fill_in('address', :with => '10018')

internet.save_and_open_page

[real output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBaee.png)
[expected/desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbyyz.png)
The expected result is that when I open the page, everything is filled in; however, when I open the page what I see is two blank dropdowns but the third one is filled with "Integra" so only that part is working. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save_and_open_page` save the current state of the html elements with their attributes.  That doesn't include the state of the html elements properties, so it may not reflect the actual current state of the page (eg. changing the value property of an element does not change the value attribute, and the attribute is what gets saved).  If you really want to see the current state you should be using `save_and_open_screenshot`.

Additionally, is there a reason you're passing `visible: false` to all those `select` calls?  If you really need to use `visible: false` to find the elements then the select should be failing since you'd be doing something a user couldn't.